# My subpane is not being added into my main compiler JavaFX

Tags: inheritance, javafx

my terminology is probably super wrong but I'm trying to create a class that inherits from the Pane class to organize my code a bit. When I try to use this subPane, nothing appears at the spot where my class should add the stuff.

Here is the code:
(Main class)

```
package ui;

//I have all the imports but there is too much code apperantly...

public class ElectronicStoreView extends Application {
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        Pane mainPain = new Pane();
        Button reset = new Button("Reset Store");
        Button add_cart = new Button("Add to Cart");
        Button remove_cart = new Button("Remove from \nCart");
        Button complete = new Button("Complete Sale");
        ListView<Product> popular = new ListView<Product>();
        ListView<Product> stock = new ListView<Product>();
        ListView<Product> cart = new ListView<Product>();
        Label t_popular = new Label("Most popular items:");
        Label t_stock = new Label("Store stock");
        Label t_cart = new Label("Cart");
        SumPane summary = new SumPane();
        ObservableList<Product> products = FXCollections.observableArrayList(ElectronicStoreCreator.createStore().products);

        summary.relocate(8, 25);
        
        //there's some code here but stackoverflow is getting angry at me

        ...

        mainPain.getChildren().addAll(reset, remove_cart, complete, add_cart, popular, stock, cart, t_cart, t_popular, t_stock, summary);

        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPain, 800, 400);
        primaryStage.setTitle(ElectronicStoreCreator.createStore().getName());
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

(custom Pane class)

```
package ui;

import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class SumPane extends Pane {
    public SumPane(){
        Pane mainPane = new Pane();
        Label summary = new Label("Store Summary");
        Label l_sales = new Label("Sales:");
        Label l_revenue = new Label("Revenue:");
        Label l_persale = new Label("$/Sale:");
        TextField sales = new TextField();
        TextField revenue = new TextField();
        TextField persale = new TextField();

        ... //stackoverflow is still angry at me

        mainPane.getChildren().addAll(summary, l_sales, l_revenue, l_persale, sales, revenue, persale);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Add the code for class Product

Comment: StackOverflow won't let me add it into the actual post so here's a [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiyDPUbUVrHo1T5lP1dpYcXMEI00?e=idGL3J) to the class in my onedrive. I'm not sure how that really maters tho, all the code that includes that works as intended.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I didn't realize I also had to add it to the class itself! It seems so obvious now that I know. I'll keep your suggestions and corrections in mind.